# How can I make the system recognize the user in WP7 application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want "remember me" check in my login page in my windows phone 7 application. How can I do that? How can I make the system recognize the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.aspx) class to save the user login details in the Windows phone memory.

And you can again check the login details from IsolatedStorage, to verify the users authenticity.

Check this link for an example of [IsolatedStorage Usage](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/)